# Extracting long lines from images with short lines as noise?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have working on a project to extract out the long lines from the image given below. I have no idea how to remove rest of the short lines and small dots from the image. Please give me some hints. My interest lines are both side long lines and middle ones.

[image]

After applying RANSAC and some thresh holding operation i get output like below

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything at all, or? Could you post it?

Comment: I tried to fit lines using RANSAC algorithm , but it was not giving me good result at all.

Comment: You will make it a lot easier for others to help you if you include a minimal example according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Have you considered doing some sort of morphology to clean up the noise?  It looks like the long lines are thicker in comparison to the short lines.  Try doing a binary morphological opening filter with a structuring element that is larger than the small lines but smaller than the larger lines

Comment: will you please giv me a example, i am not getting it

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: have you tried [hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)?

Comment: I apologize.  You tagged your post as image processing so I assumed you were familiar with the area.  Yes first question.  Do you have the image processing toolbox?  If you don't then what I have suggested will not help.  Also Shai suggested something that could work - Hough Transform.  Hough is basically a line detection algorithm.  You find histograms in the polar domain (length and angle) and you threshold on the bins.  The bins with the highest counts will most likely correspond to the prominent lines in your image.

Comment: yes i have whole matlab package, and i will try all this                  thank you shai and rayryeng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing you have the image processing toolbox, you can follow the suggestions of @rayryeng and @Shai and do something like this:

Morphological filtering:

```
BW1=bwareaopen(YourOriginalBWImage, 100);
```

Filtered image:

[image]

Hough transform (adapted from [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/detect-lines-in-images.html)):

```
[H,theta,rho] = hough(BW1);
P = houghpeaks(H,7,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
lines = houghlines(BW1,theta,rho,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',3);
figure, imshow(YourOriginalBWImage), hold on
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
end
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: +1. Nice!  Cool to see it actually being put to work :)

Answer (score 3):

For detecting straight lines, better use the well known method of [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6bDn.png');
bw = rgb2gray( imcrop( bw, [85 35 390 290] ) ) > 128; % crop and threshold image
[H,T,R] = hough(bw,'RhoResolution',0.5,'ThetaResolution',0.5);
P  = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))),'NHoodSize',[31, 11]);
lines = houghlines(bw,T,R,P,'FillGap',25,'MinLength',30);
% display the result
figure;imshow(bw);hold on;
for k = 1:length(lines), 
    xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
    plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
end
```

You'll end up with something like

[image]

Comment: +1 I didn't even know imread could read from online sources.  I'd give more for the code being totally reproducible, but alas :(